# SQL server stored procedure not returning the value

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jakarta-ee

below is my stored procedure I am calling from the Java program, I want to return if any record exits in the database, Here everything is working fine, but when if or else condition executes, it doe not return any value, Because in the Java am storing the return value in the variable file_generation and this variable is always holding the value 1.

```
USE [esp_server]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[cs_file_generation_lock]    Script Date: 3/7/2017 1:26:21 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cs_file_generation_lock]
    @pid INTEGER
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE @X_LOCK INTEGER;
    DECLARE @records INTEGER;
    DECLARE @FLAG INT = 0;
    DECLARE @FLAG1 INT = 1;

        IF exists (SELECT PID from cs_file_generation_flag)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO cs_file_generation_flag VALUES(4056,@FLAG)
                    Return @FLAG
                END

        ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO cs_file_generation_flag VALUES(@pid,@FLAG1)
                    Return @FLAG1       
                END 


END

Below is my java code
try
            {
                Connection cn = null;
                CallableStatement stmt = null;
                try
                {
                    cn = JdbcUtils.getConnection();
                    long pid = ConfigServer.getPID();

                    stmt = cn.prepareCall("{call cs_file_generation_lock(?)}");
                    stmt.setLong(1, pid);
                    int file_generation = stmt.executeUpdate();
                    JdbcUtils.commitAndClose(cn, stmt);
                    if(file_generation == 1)
                    {
                        trace1 = TerminalIdTracer.getInstance();
                        trace1.log(ConfigServerTrace.INFO, "--------------file generation process will start and the file generation value is-- " + file_generation + "process ID :" + pid);
                        new PreProcess().go(args);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        trace1.log(ConfigServerTrace.INFO, "---------------Please wait the other file generation is in process---------------" + file_generation);

                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    JdbcUtils.cleanup(cn, stmt);
                }

            }
```

Comment: We need a lot more information about what you're trying to do, what's happening, and what you expect to happen...  Sample data and desired results go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you're trying to call [Stored Procedure with a Return Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-a-return-status). In this case you should register your return value, and specify it in the call:

```
stmt = cn.prepareCall("{?=call cs_file_generation_lock(?)}");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
stmt.setLong(2, pid);
stmt.execute();
System.out.println("Flag: " + stmt.getInt(1));
```